# How to join strings systematically in pairs of two in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a program that takes strings from a file - file.txt

```
apple
banana
horse
love
purple
```

and then joins the first word with every single other one and so on.
The result should look like this:

```
applebanana
applehorse
applelove
applepurple
bananaapple
bananahorse
bananalove
bananapurple
horseapple
etc.
```

I get that I should probably use the join function, but I don't know how exactly? (If that makes sense, I am super sorry)

I tried also using zip, but couldn't make it word, so I leave it up to the professionals! <3
(I also use python 3)
If u need more info I will try to respond as fast as I can! Thank you all!

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.product`. That will generate a few too many pairs, but those are easily filtered out.

Comment: Is there anything you have tried already? You should at least try to figure something out before you post a question here.

Comment: (Actually, look at `itertools.permutations`.)

Comment: Google searches are easy. read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-all-possible-pairs-in-list/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what [`itertools.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) does.

> Return successive `r` length permutations of elements in the *iterable*.

```
from itertools import permutations

with open(<your_file>) as f:
    lst = [line.strip() for line in f]

for i, j in permutations(lst, r=2):
    print(i + j)
```

output:

```
applebanana
applehorse
applelove
applepurple
bananaapple
bananahorse
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words = []
with open(file_name, "r") as fp:
    words = [line.replace('\n', '') for line in fp]
for wi in words:
    for wj in words:
        print(f"{wi}{wj}")
```

Comment: Please don't just write code for questions that have shown no attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: The `replace` function requires a replacement argument. Also, you don't need to declare `words` as an empty list if you will use a list comprehension later on.

Comment: Also, don't post answers that have no explanation, only code. They _might_ seem interesting at the moment, but become problematic in the long run

Answer (score 0):

```
#say you have a list of words 
l = ['apple', 'banana', 'horse', 'love', 'purple']

for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(len(l)):
        if i != j:
            print(l[i]+l[j])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).